# How to play a beep sound clicking on a disabled control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want the following on the btn1.Click:

```
if (btn1.Enabled == false) System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

Is there a way to play the beep although btn1 is disabled ?

In fact, I need something like this to have by default:

```
foreach (controls c in Form1.Controls)
if (c is clicked && c.Enabled == false)
System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

Comment: If the control is disabled it won't receive the click event. You'll have to store the "enabled" state separately and check on your flag in the click event handler.

Comment: The grayed out look should indicate that its disabled and if you wanna add anything else atleast a `ToolTip` like disabled would be a better choice.

Comment: Why would you want to beep when the user clicks on a disabled button? The appearance of the button already tells the user that "I am disabled".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a click event to the form and get the control that is at the position of the click:

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var p = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
  var c = GetChildAtPoint(p);
  if (c != null && c.Enabled == false)
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a Button is disabled, it won't receive Click events. So the only way is enable it and use a custom flag to store the state.

Comment: @Buena create your own `bool` variable and use it instead of using `btn1.Enabled`

Comment: It would be a weird User experience that on clicking it would do nothing.

Comment: In this case it would not be weird. I simulate a form by a panel and don't want user to do anything before he "closes" the panel (i.e. makes it invisible by ok button).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do this in the OnMouseClick event of your form (receiving a MouseEventArgs e):

```
Control control = GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);

if (control != null)
{
}
```

From that, you can do some dirty things to retrieve the control type and its state and beep if necessary. Anyway, I'd hate to use an application beeping all the time ;-)

Comment: without beep user could keep clicking on the control. He may think that maybe something is wrong with mouse or keyboard...

Answer (score 1):

If you are making controls disabled manually , instead of disabling the buttons you can just change the button's style to disabled. And on click event check the button's style. If you can explain why you want that functionality we can help more maybe